# How to find an expression and replace it with certain text?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, expression, tokenize

I have an xml file with tokens in the middle of a sentence. 
For example: #his/her_caps# test is complete.

I want to search the xml file for any #(text)# token and replace it with its proper pronoun, so the tag above I'd replace with His or Her. How do I search for the #(text)# expression?

I don't understand how to use the tokenizer if that's what I'd use and not sure how to right a regex for that either.

I am finishing a project someone else started and this is what they had, but they couldn't get it to work. I just want to know how to search an xml file for the tags.

Attempt one:

```
File inputXML = new File("template.xml"); // creates new input file
        DocumentBuilderFactory parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); // new instance of doc builder
        DocumentBuilder dParser = parser.newDocumentBuilder(); // calls it
        Document doc = dParser.parse(inputXML); // parses file
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList pList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Verbiage"); // gets element by tag name and places into list to begin parsing

        int gender = 1; // gender has to be taken from the response file, it is hard coded for testing purposes
        //System.out.println("----------------------------"); // new line

        // loops through the list of Verbiage tags
        for (int temp = 0; temp < pList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node pNode = pList.item(0); // sets node to temp

            if (pNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { // if the node type = the element node
                Element eElement = (Element) pNode;
                NodeList pronounList = doc.getElementsByTagName("pronoun"); // gets a list of pronoun element tags

                if (gender == 0) { // if the gender is male

                    int count1 = 0;
                    while (count1 < pronounList.getLength()) {

                        if ("#resp_he/she_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count1).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count1).setTextContent("he");
                        }

                        if ("#resp_he/she_caps#".equals(pronounList.item(count1).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count1).setTextContent("He");
                        }

                        if ("#resp_his/her_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count1).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count1).setTextContent("his");
                        }
                        if ("#resp_his/her_caps#".equals(pronounList.item(count1).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count1).setTextContent("His");
                        }

                        if ("#resp_him/her_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count1).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count1).setTextContent("him");
                        }
                        count1++;
                    }
                    pNode.getNextSibling();

                } else if (gender == 1) { // female
                    int count = 0;
                    while (count < pronounList.getLength()) {

                        if ("#he/she_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count).setTextContent("she");
                        }

                        if ("#he/she_caps#".equals(pronounList.item(count).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count).setTextContent("She");
                        }

                        if ("#his/her_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count).setTextContent("her");
                        }
                        if ("#his/her_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count).setTextContent("Her");
                        }

                        if ("#him/her_lc#".equals(pronounList.item(count).getTextContent())) {
                            pronounList.item(count).setTextContent("her");
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    pNode.getNextSibling();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please help us with the code that you have tried.

Comment: `xmlString = xmlString.replace("##his/her_caps##", "HER");` ?

Comment: @Tauqir I haven't found how to do it hence why I am here haha. I don't know whether to use a tokenizer or if there's another way to search for the expression.

Comment: @Bohemian How would I initiate xmlString?

Comment: @Felicia the XML must come from somewhere. If it's a string, you could just use my suggestion. If it's a document  object, I would turn it into a String then do as above. It's a string problem, so a string approach is appropriate IMHO. Otherwise you would have to know which element types the placeholders can be found in. You could use XSLT if you have a strong sense of self loathing and like pain.

Comment: @Felicia btw, one way to read the file in as a String: `String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("template.xml")));`

Comment: @Bohemian is content = xmlString or am I using two different strings?

Comment: Yes, I meant `xmlString`.

Comment: I tried this and I'm not sure it's doing what I need it to do :/ ..I am reading an xml file and I want to parse it to find any tags that are surrounded by hashtags like #(text)# and then I want to replace that tag with a word. When this is done this file will be saved and converted to a pdf to read.

Comment: You should look into XSLT for most tasks involving transforming XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex in notepad ++

^#.{0,}#$ should find all the things between #

Can't remember if the # needs to be escaped( #) though. I don't think so.

Also if you need to find him or her specifically you can add.  ^#.{0,}his.{0,}#$

Comment: If you use ^#(.{0,})his(.{0,})#$.  To find it you can replace it with #\1His\2#

Comment: I have no idea how regex works... This is part of my problem haha. What do I do with the regex in notepad++?

Comment: Use the search/ replace function I think it's under edit on the top.

Comment: Do a search with ^#(.{0,})His(.{0,})#$. First to make sure it's selecting the right tags. And make sure you have Regex checked

Comment: The code has to be able to do this search on its own, not manually.

Comment: Oh my bad I missed that